# Users upload view

Tags: python, django

When users upload a file in the directory MEDIA_ROOT ("usermedia") 
all upload files in usermedia directory are in the PIN.pdf format. Each user has its unique PIN number (11 numbers) which is entered during user registration.

I want in my app to create view.html file, in which will be display upload files. not for all users. users see only their own files

Answer (score 3):

You can capture path of files uploaded my user somewhere (in db through model), then filter model by user and display all uploaded files.

Comment: +1 should take a look at `django.filetransfer` and use it as your generic file upload app. Then do what Amit suggests. That's currently how I do mine. We have an ID for the upload (look at how tumblr / facebook does with their image name..), then construct it with your image storage server host name)

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest (but not the best) is to store uploads MEDIA_ROOT + ID of user. But it is not safe and good. In your view you could list all files in user upload directory.